# Running gwan on raspberry pi?

Tags: raspberry-pi, g-wan

Tried the 32bit gwan on raspberry pi but got cannot execute binary file.

Any ways to run on wheeze raspberry pi?

Will be great if we can do test on it.

Comment: how you was start start the binary? as super user? what is the error msg?

Comment: gwan> cannot execute binary file. 

and exited

Comment: make sure you have the 32bit bin. then check your /var/log/syslog or /var/log/message if there will be more information while start ./gwan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Raspberry Pi computers uses `ARM CPUs` you are using a version of G-WAN compiled for `Intel-compatible CPUs`.

This just cannot work (unless the Raspberry Pi is running an x86 CPU emulator).

Comment: when truly free, do make one for android first then arm cpu? thanks! i mean it's just a cool factor that's all. not really important.